Getting a long term job in Schengen and ID card while on a short term visa?
If you go to a Schengen country on some short term C visa, but you either have applied for a job beforehand or apply while there, do you have to go back to your embassy?
I see many people travel to another country, where they will get an ID card and a job. Despite the fact they came in on a short term visa, thats only a sticker in your passport.
Is this completely legal or illegal? Forcing you to go back to your embassy seems logical but on the other hand you were already there about your short term visa, so what would be the point?
Why does it appear to be illegal to do this in one country (come in seasonal in Romania and get hired in Romania) while it seems to be less illegal or works better to leave Romania with your seasonal visa and apply for a job in another country? I think Germany even counts the application for work permit as temporary visa extension until a decision is reached.
What if you plan ahead, get your permit for job 1 (seasonal) and also get your second work permit for say 2 years too.
In these cases should you exit and reenter schengen, to be safe?

This is not harmonized across the Schengen area, and every country will have its own policy in this regard.
For example, germany allows people from Australia, Canada, Israel, Japan, New Zealand, the Republic of Korea, the UK, and the USA to apply for a residence permit directly at the Ausländerbehörde while in the country on a short-term visa-free entry, while people with other citizenships may not do so.
Meanwhile, france has no such program and only allows applications for residence permits from within the country if they are family members of EU citizens and in other similarly narrow circumstances.
You will have to research the specific policy of the country you are considering moving to and how it applies to people of your nationality and with your reason for staying long-term.

For Germany, the United Kingdom is also contained in the list of countries that may apply for a residence permit directly in Germany. §41(1) AufenthV - Einzelnorm

(+1) There are a couple of other scenarios in which you can apply for a residence permit from within the country in France: if you are a long term resident or hold a Blue Card from another EU country. Just like the exception for members of the family of an EU citizen, it's the bare minimum mandated by EU rules.

@Relaxed I have talked to people who did go to france on a seasona visa to work there, presumably long term. So how did they do that? What if application takes place before you enter France, but when you enter, you just go get your ID card. But how is the embassy skipped?

@user1721135 Hard to know, there is a lot in your question that's unclear. What citizenship? What was their status? Are you positive they were able to take up residence without any period of illegal stay? What do you mean by ID card? A residence permit? Beyond that, it depends on what you mean by “seasonal”. Anything longer than 3 months counts as a long-stay visa and does allow you to transition to another status, same thing for students, etc. The rules we are talking about apply to people who entered on a Schengen short-stay visa.

@Relaxed this guy was Nepali, I just randomly saw him while on vacation and asked him. He was there for 3 months, then France. If you are longer than 3 months, you are allowed specifically in France? With ID I mean like 3 year visa based on work permit.

@user1721135 did your Nepali friend actually have a valid work permit for France? A lot of people enter the Schengen Area one way or another and then (over)stay and work illegally. Even if they only get paid half of minimum wage (because they’re illegal), that’s still a lot more than they would get for a similar job at home. Some industries employ tons of illegals. Enforcement is highly variable from one country to one country to another, and over time.

'With ID I mean like 3 year visa based on work permit.' In the Schengen area (as apposed to other countries) an ID has nothing to do with any authorization of stay or employment for third country nationals. With the exception of Italy, ID cards are only issued to citizens as proof of the person's identity.

@MarkJohnson I would say it's a little more complicated than that.  It's not entirely unreasonable to call a work permit or residence permit an "ID" even if it's not the term used by the EU or by those of us who follow the EU's technical jargon.  And whether any given document authorizes résidence, employment, or both is variable enough from one country to the next that confusion can easily arise around terms that are ostensibly more precise such as "work permit" or "residence permit."

@user1721135 In general, a document that allows you to stay longer than 3 months will be specific to France and also allow you to transition to another status without having to leave France or go to a consulate again. The kind of short-term visa that comes with the restrictions you are asking about are visa for stays under 90 days.

@phoog Actually it is very unreasonable to assume that an ID is anything other than an abbreviation for identification: any official card or document with your name and photograph or other information on it that you use to prove who you are.

@MarkJohnson That's exactly what you can do with a French residence permit so it seems we are all in agreement?

TRC is a form of ID. In the context its clear what it means.


Is this completely legal or illegal?

It is neither. EU law defines a few situations where it should be legal but individual EU countries are free to define their own rules in all other situations and the rules do differ so there is no general answer. As Mike explained, the country you want to stay in, the reason for your stay, and your own citizenship can all make a difference.

Forcing you to go back to your embassy seems logical but on the other hand you were already there about your short term visa, so what would be the point?

The point is that if you are out of the country when you get a refusal, you cannot decide to just stay put and it is much more difficult for you to reenter. If you are in the country when you get a refusal, you have fewer incentives to leave on your own and finding and removing you can be complicated and costly.

Why does it appear to be illegal to do this in one country (come in seasonal in Romania and get hired in Romania) while it seems to be less illegal or works better to leave Romania with your seasonal visa and apply for a job in another country?

I don't know about Romania specifically but there are similar programs elsewhere in Europe. They are designed to make sure people leave after the end of their permit and only come back when they are needed by their employer. There are several (ethically questionable) reasons for these policies: Alleviating concerns about foreign laborers immigrating and building a life in the country while still exploiting their cheap labor and making them more dependent on their employer.

What if you plan ahead, get your permit for job 1 (seasonal) and also get your second work permit for say 2 years too.
In these cases should you exit and reenter Schengen, to be safe?

If you do get a residence permit in the country you are in, there is usually no need to leave and reenter, for that would really be pointless even from the narrow perspective of restrictive immigration policies. The real bottleneck is being allowed to apply for a permit in-country.
